# Problem with repeated cells evaluation using tags

Tags: syntax, cells

Consider the following code:

```
BlockEvaluation[tag_] := Block[{},
  nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
  NotebookFind[nb, tag, All, CellTags];
  SelectionEvaluate[nb]
  ]
Xlist = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
Do[quantity[X] = X, {X, {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}}]
list = {};
XlistComputation = 
 DialogInput[{choice = {}}, 
  Column[{Row[{"Select the X list:"}], 
    Pane[TogglerBar[Dynamic[choice], Xlist, 
      Appearance -> "Vertical" -> {Automatic, 6}], 
     ImageSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
     Scrollbars -> {False, True}], 
    Button["OK", DialogReturn[choice]]}]]
Do[
 Xval = XlistComputation[[i]];
 BlockEvaluation["evaluation"];
 , {i, 1, Length[XlistComputation], 1}
 ]
```

It first asks to select elements of a list, and then repeatedly runs some section by its tag by iterating over the list.

The section is made of one simple command:

```
list = Join[list, {Xval}]
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Let us assume that I selected `XlistComputation = {"A","B","C"}`. Then the output (`list`) of the section that is repeatedly launched should be just `{"A","B","C"}`. Instead, it is `{"C","C","C"}`. Could you please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: I assume that SelectionEvaluate is actually putting the selected cells on some sort of evaluation queue. The evaluation of the Do must finish before proceeding to the rest of the queue. By the time the Do is finished, the value of Xval is set to be the last element of XlistComputation.

Comment: @lericr : thanks! Is there a workaround?

Comment: Well, I can't really know what your whole vision is for this computation, but my general advice is to not rely on side effects. You've got some cells that you want to evaluate, and those cells depend on global variables. What you're trying to do is carefully manage the state of those global variables while evaluating the cells. I would try to find a way to create functions that only depend on local variables (arguments) and then call those functions with the arguments you want each time.

Comment: I suppose you could also put some of the body of your Do into one of the cells with the "evaluate" tag. So, have a cell that has the "evaluate" tag and has this code: `Xval = XlistComputation[[i++]]`. Somewhere you'll need to initialize `i`. I personally am not happy with this, as I'd prefer to functional approach I already described, but maybe this constitutes a "workaround" for you.